# Retrieve server side object values using getInfo()

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I'm having trouble converting a server-side object which contains a number into a client-side value effectively. I'm using GEE python API. getInfo() function takes a lot of time to process.

```py
# Get the sum of pixel values in the entire image
sum_value = multiplied_image.reduceRegion(
  reducer=ee.Reducer.sum(),
  geometry=geom,
  scale=100  # Set the appropriate scale for your analysis
)

# Sum_value is an Earth Engine object
sum_value = sum_value.get('sm_rootzone')

# Convert to client-side number using ee.Number
sum_value_client = ee.Number(sum_value).getInfo()
# print(sum_value_client)

# Append the results to the data list
data.append([Date_pre, layer, sum_value_client]
```

Answer (score 0):

How long is too long? Without the rest of your code it's difficult to assess whether this can be improved. You might also find that using the batch environment is a better solution for your analysis. Read more about it here:

https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/processing_environments

Your goal would then be to create and start an export task:

https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/exporting_tables